# comma after every element in list instead of the last one

Tags: python, list, arraylist, while-loop

I want to make a function which would add comma after every word in list instead of the last one. I tried to do it with a while-loop so it could stop before the comma reaches the last word, but the output of the code is not doing its job.

```
list = ['Sadzo', 'Nimadaro', 'Duol']
wordIndex = 0
LenghtUnderIndex = len(list[wordIndex])

while wordIndex <= len(list):
  list.insert(LenghtUnderIndex, ', ')
  wordIndex += 1
  break

print (*list)
```

Comment: When you say "instead of the last one", do you mean "*except* for the last one"?

Answer (score 1):

This is what `join` is for.

```
out = ','.join(list)
```

However, do not name your variable `list`.  That hides the Python type by the same name.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use:

```
for x in range(len(list) - 1):
  list[x] = list[x] + ","
```